# Open Office Impress

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, openoffice-impress

I have seen that in some question around presentation you suggest using OO Impress for this. I am trying to show multiple presentation in a non fullscreen window, but havent been very successful so far. Ideally I want to be able to move this presentation windows around the screen. I have searched the Open Office forum but the is almost nothing concerning this topic and noone seems to know the answer to my question. Im trying to do this in C#. 
I would be very thankfull if you can give me some directions, how to do this.

Thank you